# Use only the most recent row in oracle start with/connect by prior query

Tags: oracle, hierarchical-query

My hierarchical query looks like this:

```
select ID, PARENT_ID, START_TIME
FROM PROCESS
START WITH ID='X'
CONNECT BY ID=PRIOR PARENT_ID
```

My problem is that there are rows with the same ID 'X' and I only want the most recent one returned (when a process is duplicated, its ID is the same - can't change that).  Additionally, I only want it to connect by prior parent ID for the row that is most recent as well.

From the docs, it appears that I can't do a query in the connect by to get just the latest prior parent_id - will I need to filter in code or is there a way to do this within the query?

Comment: Edit your question and show sample data and expected results. Only text data, no images please.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function to get the latest row for each `ID`:

```
SELECT ID,
       PARENT_ID,
       START_TIME
FROM   (
  SELECT p.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY id
           ORDER BY start_time DESC
         ) AS rn
  FROM   process p
)
WHERE rn = 1
START WITH ID = 'X'
CONNECT BY ID = PRIOR PARENT_ID;
```

Comment: Thanks MT0.  This is better, but it only gets the first level of latest process.  If A is parent of B and B is parent of C and B was duplicated, those duplicates are showing up.  The duplicates of C are not.  It seems that the connect by ID = PRIOR PARENT_ID will always match more rows when they exist?